# SQL Injection vulnerabilities

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

We have a ASP.NET/C# website. Our developers are off shore in Asia and I just discovered they have been placing raw SQL on the site front end.

I am worried we are now vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Does anyone know how I can detect vulnerabilities on the site and what is the best way to close the door on them?

Comment: first thing would be to remove all inline (raw) SQL from front end and back end and only use stored procedures passing values as parameters

Comment: Front end as in like... in forms as hidden inputs and stuff?

Comment: Yes as in, input fields on forms/pages

Comment: @Davide stored procedures add no more security than correctly parameterised regular SQL, but make deployment more complex; no need to SPROC here, IMO. Just use parameters correctly.

Comment: @Marc I know, but in general is way better to have stored proc in the server where you can control them and eventually profile, enhance, analyze, precompile etc... instead of same logic all around the C# code then to fix a small thing you need to deploy the binaries again and you are not safe when schema changes... anyway I see your point and the question here is not about SPROC vs SQL in the front end...

Comment: @Davide maybe I'm biased because we have a really easy deployment strategy here; it is just as easy to deploy binaries, and: SPROCs are a pain, because of timing... if it changes the behaviour at all, you're in trouble no matter *how* you slice the farm, upgrade half the servers, run the SPROC script and then *really quickly* flip the cluster over... if the app tier owns the SQL, no problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trying to detect the vulnerabilities from the front *may* help, but really you should be looking at the code, in particular all code that relates to DbCommand, SqlCommand, etc. The key point, as you clearly know, is never to concatenate user input into a query, but to parameterise it. There are good tools available that can make this parameterisation easy to do - or at least, easier than doing it manually. For example, if you have:

```
using(var cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) {
    cmd.CommandText = "delete from Orders where id = " + id;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

then a tool like dapper-dot-net will allow you to do things like:

```
conn.Execute("delete from Orders where id = @id", new {id});
```

which is **less** code, largely a copy-paste, but is fully injection-safe and allows query-plan re-use.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [Scrawlr](https://h30406.www3.hp.com/campaigns/2008/wwcampaign/1-57C4K/index.php) or [Acunetix](http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection.htm)

These are tools to scan a website for vulnerabilities, especially for SQL Injection.  Another way is to sign up to one of the PCI-DSS compliance companies.  We use SecurityMetrics and normally banks offer discounts to these.

Comment: useful links but two more sentences to explain what those are would be helpful so no need to follow the link only to see where it goes

Answer (score 1):

First check out this article: [How To: Protect From SQL Injection in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx)

I would make sure all the you either use stored procedures exlusively or if you have regualr sql commands you use them only with paramters and never dynamically build the content of the [CommandText property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtext.aspx)

Comment: stored procedures add no more security than correctly parameterised regular SQL, but make deployment more complex; no need to SPROC here, IMO. Just use parameters correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Well, i would order them to send you the source code and perform a code view (or have one done by a relatively experiend developer.

Comment: I think a refund is in order too!